# SAPUI5 TreeTable in Eclipse with XML View

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to create a Hierarchical Tree Table in Eclipse Neon for a SAPUI5 Project.

I've looked at the following SDK for TreeTables : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.TreeTable.BasicODataTreeBinding/preview

I'm not getting any joy when executing my project, nothing is displayed in my chrome web browser.

Please see below my various code snippets, where am I going wrong?

Common.view.xml :

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:tree="sap.ui.table"
        controllerName="testcommon.Common" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Page>
    <content>

        <tree:TreeTable id="treeTable"
    selectionMode="Single"
    enableColumnReordering="false"
    expandFirstLevel="false"
    rows="{
        path : '/table',
        parameters : {
            countMode: 'Inline',
            treeAnnotationProperties : {
                hierarchyLevelFor : 'HierarchyLevel',
                hierarchyNodeFor : 'NodeID',
                hierarchyParentNodeFor : 'ParentNodeID',
                hierarchyDrillStateFor : 'DrillState'
            }
        }
    }">
    <tree:columns>
        <tree:Column label="Description">
                <Text text="Description"/>
        </tree:Column>
        <tree:Column label="HierarchyLevel">
                <Text text="HierarchyLevel" wrapping="false" />
        </tree:Column>
        <tree:Column label="NodeID">
                <Text text="NodeID" wrapping="false" />
        </tree:Column>
        <tree:Column label="ParentNodeID">
                <Text text="ParentNodeID" wrapping="false" />
        </tree:Column>
  </tree:columns>
</tree:TreeTable>
    </content>
</Page>
```

Common.controller.js :

```js
sap.ui.controller("testcommon.Common", {

/**
* Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
* Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
* @memberOf testcommon.Common
*/
 onInit: function() {
  var model1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
  model1.loadData("model/mock.json");
  this.getView().setModel(model1, "model1"); 
   
  jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");
 },
```

index.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
  

  <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.m,sap.ui.table"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
  </script>
  <!-- add sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3 and/or other libraries to 'data-sap-ui-libs' if required -->

  <script>
    sap.ui.localResources("testcommon");
    var view = sap.ui.view({id:"idCommon1", viewName:"testcommon.Common", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
    view.placeAt("content");
  </script>

 </head>
 <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
  <div id="content"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

mock.json file which is in folder model under WebContent :

> {"table": 
>   [
>       {
>           "NodeID": 1,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 0,
>           "Description": "1",
>           "ParentNodeID": null,
>           "DrillState": "expanded"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 2,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 0,
>           "Description": "2",
>           "ParentNodeID": null,
>           "DrillState": "expanded"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 3,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 0,
>           "Description": "3",
>           "ParentNodeID": null,
>           "DrillState": "expanded"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 4,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 1,
>           "Description": "1.1",
>           "ParentNodeID": 1,
>           "DrillState": "leaf"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 5,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 1,
>           "Description": "1.2",
>           "ParentNodeID": 1,
>           "DrillState": "expanded"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 6,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 2,
>           "Description": "1.2.1",
>           "ParentNodeID": 5,
>           "DrillState": "leaf"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 7,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 2,
>           "Description": "1.2.2",
>           "ParentNodeID": 5,
>           "DrillState": "leaf"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 8,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 1,
>           "Description": "2.1",
>           "ParentNodeID": 2,
>           "DrillState": "leaf"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 9,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 1,
>           "Description": "2.2",
>           "ParentNodeID": 2,
>           "DrillState": "leaf"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 10,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 1,
>           "Description": "2.3",
>           "ParentNodeID": 2,
>           "DrillState": "leaf"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 11,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 1,
>           "Description": "3.1",
>           "ParentNodeID": 3,
>           "DrillState": "expanded"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 12,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 2,
>           "Description": "3.1.1",
>           "ParentNodeID": 11,
>           "DrillState": "expanded"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 13,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 3,
>           "Description": "3.1.1.1",
>           "ParentNodeID": 12,
>           "DrillState": "leaf"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 14,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 3,
>           "Description": "3.1.1.2",
>           "ParentNodeID": 12,
>           "DrillState": "leaf"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 15,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 3,
>           "Description": "3.1.1.3",
>           "ParentNodeID": 12,
>           "DrillState": "leaf"
>       },
>       {
>           "NodeID": 16,
>           "HierarchyLevel": 3,
>           "Description": "3.1.1.4",
>           "ParentNodeID": 12,
>           "DrillState": "leaf"
>       }
>   ]}

When run index.html as Web App Preview I only see a blank screen and I don't see any errors in F12 Developer tools in Chrome. Please assist.

Thanks lots,
Mark

Comment: Did you check the `src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"`?

Comment: Hi Binh I have all the SAPUI5 Core Libraries loaded in the project, what do you mean with above statement?

Comment: Hi, blank screen mostly appears because of wrong source or maybe, wrong file path. I think at least there is one error in the console tab of Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Thanks Binh, I'm still finding my way around SAPUI5, how would I know if the local json model was read and loaded successfully and how I would I be able to see the contents in model1?

Comment: Hi, you can try to define the local model in 'manifest.json' file. That way, SAPUI5 will automatically load your model while initiate itself.

Comment: Hi Binh, you know what happens, when I refresh browser then I see the table headers but just for a few milliseconds then it disappears again and I have blank screen, very strange to try and explain. Every time I keep hitting refresh I can see the table headers for a brief moment before it disappears, any other ideas?

Comment: At first sight, your code looks fine. I'm trying to reproduce the issue. If possible, can you upload your project?

Comment: Hi Binh I'm trying to upload my project but not sure how, I'm new to Stack Overflow, can you guide me please or could I possibly email it to you please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `treeAnnotationProperties` with an OData model. It won't work with a JSON model.

Try to structure your data differently and bind it using the `arrayNames` parameter, like in the example below:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.TreeTable.JSONTreeBinding/code

Comment: Hi Guilherme

Thanks for the advice, I tried the above SDK sample you suggested using WebIDE and it working fine, then I tried this same sample using Eclipse Neon and creating a SAPUI5 Project in Eclipse and in Google Chrome Debug it is giving me the following error :

Uncaught Error: Path path:'/catalog/clothing', parameters: {arrayNames:['categories']} must start with a / 

I'm confused now, how come it is working fine from WebIDE but not from Eclipse?

Thanks lots!
Mark